# SQl Server profile result for Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server-2008

My program gets error as Timeout expired. 
This is the sql profiler result

[image]

It takes so long time before save stored procedure and then return timeout expired message. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the two marked ones are the issue because they seem to come from Management Studio and I don't think your program is running through management studio?

Comment: @marc_s , Sure that come from program running. Else has another reason ?